# Alomofire POST request in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, alamofire

I am using the following code in my swift 2.0 project. I cannot add Alamofire.request though I added "import Alamofire". I have to create object of Alamofire and then access through it.

This is how I create the object :

```
let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
manager.request(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")!))

let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

manager.request(.POST, "url", parameters: parameters)
.responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
print("request: \(request)")
}
```

I am new to both Alamofire and swift. Can anybody tell how can I get response from the above code in a completion handler and why I cannot use Alamofire.request instead of manager.request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request not always in JSON please check your request :

Following are examples to use Alamofire with the Swift 2 :

**GET - JSON**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/", parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON { (req, res, json) -> Void in
    print("\(res?.allHeaderFields)")
    print("\(json.value!)")
}
```

**POST - without JSON**

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"], encoding: .URL, headers: nil).response { (req, res, data, error) -> Void in
    print(res)
    print(data)

    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(dataString)
}
```

Comment: Thank you brother. Your code was perfect for me. Can you also let me know why I cannot autocomplete Alomofire.request in my xcode, though I am not getting any error if I copy your code. For autocompletion I have to add an object of Alomofire and then proceed further.

Comment: You have created instance of Alamofire and also you have created an URL request no need to do it. Alamofire will take care of it. Keep it up @user3730935

Comment: But without that I cannot auto complete my coding!! :(

Answer (score 4):

**Please see my Post method and Hope It helps**

**Post Method:**

```
/**
    ** POST Method for calling API
    *  Services gateway
    *  Method  get response from server
    *  @parameter              -> requestObject: request josn object ,apiName: api endpoint
    *  @returm                 -> void
    *  @compilationHandler     -> success: status of api, response: respose from server, error: error handling
    **/
    static func getDataWithObject( requestObject: NSDictionary, apiName : NSString,
        completionHandler:
        (success : Bool, response : NSDictionary, error : ErrorType?) -> Void) {

            // Make Url
            let url = NSURL(string: apiName as String)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            //request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            // Call the method to request and wait for the response
            // @param  ->
            // @return ->
            Alamofire.request(.POST, url!, parameters:requestObject as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
                .responseJSON {responseRequest, responseResponse, responseResult in

                    // Switch for Success or Error
                    switch responseResult {

                        // If the API return succesfull response
                    case .Success(let data):

                        let data_ar = data as! NSDictionary
                        print(data_ar)
                        // Get the Status if 0 then error if 1 then succes
                        // From our server side
                        if let str = data_ar.valueForKey("OK") as? Bool {

                            // Check if the status is OK and no error from
                            // our server side
                            if ( str ) {

                                print("Response from Server %@", data_ar)

                                // Cast the response and pss to handler
                                // To notify
                                completionHandler(success: true, response:data_ar
                                    , error:responseResult.error )
                            } else {
                                print("Error from Our Server %@", data_ar)
                                let str = data_ar.valueForKey("message") as! NSString
                                self.showAlertView(str, title: "Error From Server")
                            }

                        }

                    case .Failure(let data, let error):
                        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                        print(data)
                        print((error as! NSError).localizedDescription)
                        self.showAlertView((error as! NSError).localizedDescription, title: "Error From Server")

                    }
            }
    }
```